# Finding coordinates min and max of a matrix without using min/max commands

Tags: matlab, matrix, max, min, matrix-indexing

I have this code that shows me min and max values from a random matrix without using min/max commands:

```
   m = rand(5,5)*10
    mn = m(1);
    mx = m(1);
    for ii = 2:numel(m)
        if m(ii) < mn
            mn = m(ii);
            imn = ii;
        elseif m(ii) > mx
            mx = m(ii);
            imx = ii;
        end
    end
    disp(mx)
    disp(mn)
```

How can I also find the minimum and maximum coordinate/position?
I need to do this only with the function for, or loop, and i'm using matlab version 2018a

Comment: Isn't `imn` and `imx` already the position of the min/max? Are you looking for something different?

Comment: The bug is in the initialization: `mx = m(2);` should read `mx = m(1);`

Comment: I edited it, look

Comment: There is no issue to reproduce or fix here, it's still unclear why `imx` and `imn` aren't the values you're looking for, which you've already calculated!

Comment: I need to find the position (I,J) of the min and max values from the matrix, using for function, the imx and imn dont show me the coordinates i j

Comment: @LucasTesch look at the `ind2sub` in my answer and make sure you understand how it works - this is what converts linear indices (like your `imx`, `imn`) to `ij`.

Comment: In your code you use sorting and find function, inmy work, I can not use these, Just for or circle loop

Comment: @LucasTesch Just look at the `ind2sub` part of Dev-iL's answer, not the whole thing. Use it to convert the indices in `imn` and `imx` to row/column subscripts. Alternatively, you can change your code to use a double `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
A = rand(5,5);
B = A(:);
[B,I] = sort(B);
m_min = B(1);
m_max = B(end);
index_min = I(1);
index_max = I(end);
```

- Generate the random array
- Convert the array into a vector
- Sort the vector
- Maximum is the last item
- Minimum is the first item

I have modified the code to show indices of extrema. The equivalent indices as
coordinates in the array can be found using `ind2subs`

```
coord_max = ind2subs([5,5], index_max);
coord_min = ind2subs([5,5], index_min);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with sorting:

```
function [minVal, maxVal, cMin, cMax] = q52961181(m)
if ~nargin, m = rand(5,5); end
sz = size(m);
[v,c] = sort(m(:), 'ascend');
% at this point, the *linear* indices of the minimum and the maximum are c(1) and c(end),
% respectively.
[x,y] = ind2sub(sz, c([1,end]));
assert(isequal(numel(x), numel(y), 2)); % make sure we don't have repetitions
minVal = v(1); maxVal = v(2);
cMin = [x(1), y(1)];
cMax = [x(2), y(2)];
```

Or using `find`:

```
function [minVal, maxVal, cMin, cMax] = q52961181(m)
if ~nargin, m = rand(5,5); end
[minVal,maxVal] = bounds(m,'all'); % "bounds" was introduced in R2017a
[cMin, cMax] = deal(zeros(1,2));
[cMin(1), cMin(2)] = find(m == minVal);
[cMax(1), cMax(2)] = find(m == maxVal);
```

(This solution is technically cheating, since `bounds` calls `min` and `max` internally. However, you can just use your own code instead to determine the minimum and maximum values.)

Comment: I need to do this with the function for

Comment: @LucasTesch In that case, 1) please update the question to state this requirement (consider that this is a _bad coding practice in MATLAB_); 2) see Cris' comment to the question - your solution is _almost_ correct as it is.